# Translation Editor doesn't show strings from library projects

Tags: android, android-studio, translation-editor

I'm using several library projects in my main Android application. When I open Translation Editor in Android Studio for that application it shows only strings for the main project, but not library projects (see scheenshot).

[image: illustration]

Is there any way to force Translation Editor to show all strings?

Comment: Well this translation editor is IN your main project, and not in your other project, so most likely the answer is simply "It's impossible"

Comment: How I can check in which project it is?

Comment: I've never seen an option for that :|, I mean, who wouldn't know his own strings?

Comment: "app_name" is a string from the main project. Also there are a lot of strings in library projects, that are not shown. But that library projects are shown in project explorer at the left.

Comment: The problem is that I have one strings.xml in each library project. The projects are translated in 10 languages. And now I'm trying to figure out missing translations for each language.

Comment: Then I'm sorry but I cannot helo you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was simple, but not obvious for me.

The Translation Editor shows only strings for a project, from which you open it. Since that I can open an xml layout file from project A and launch Translation Editor from it. Then open xml layout from another project B and launch Translation Editor from it too. There will be two editor views opened. And so on. Here is a screen what I've received.

[image: Problem solved!]

Hope this will help someone, because I can't find anything similar in the net.